# CSS Resetting Margin and Padding

Tags: css, box-sizing

If I use the box-sizing property to border-box, does it make resetting margin and padding to 0 irrelevant or is it still something I should do?

i.e.

```
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: It's enough to "reset" all the paddings and the margins. However, I've seen one interesting approach, where we apply `box-sizing` to `html`. And make `*` `*:after` `*:before` with inheritance of `box-sizing` which makes it easier to work with some external components that are projected with other type of `box-sizing`

Comment: What you have atm. is just fine.

Answer (score 9):

It is still relevant as the box-model just change the way your margin/padding/border being calculated in width and height.

### You can check on the below image

[image: Box model differences]

Answer (score 1):

When you set box-sizing: border-box; on an element, the padding and border of that element no longer increase its width.

cheack this out :- http://learnlayout.com/box-sizing.html